# Inventory of all GCP projects with 0 resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I need an inventory of all GCP projects that have no resources deployed in it.
I have looked at commands projects.list and gcloud asset search-all-resources
However, not clear how can accomplish what I need… projects with no resources.

Any ideas, help, examples, or documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can approach this from a billing perspective.  Filter for projects that have no spend (or very, very little).

Comment: @GlenYu beware of free tier billing for low consumption resources

Comment: It should be okay because you should still be able to see a breakdown of resources in those projects even if they're free-tier (it will show that the price is discounted)

Comment: All Google Cloud Projects contain resources. Therefore you can not inventory or search for something that does not exist.

Comment: No resource is hard to say. What is a resource? A service account is a resource, does it one for you? Often, a default VPC is created, does it a resource for you? It is for Google Cloud. Do you want to delete the unused project? You have a feature for that, but it doesn't mean it has no resources: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/google-cloud-launches-unattended-project-recommender

Comment: thank you @GlenYu for that new perspective and
guillaume blaquiere I will look at that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Asset Inventory API for that https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. Please edit your answer to show an actual solution and not only a link to the documentation. Links change/break/etc that might render your answer useless in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The google cloud asset inventory can help you with that.

On the main console search for asset inventory:
[image]

On the left side in the overview, you will find "filter results".

There is a section for projects. Click on that and and you can see projects with no resources. Hope that helps.